# How to get the custom attribute values in my catalog category list block

Tags: catalog, blocks, category, custom

I have added a custom attribute to my category.
On category product listing page i want to retrieve the values of that custom attribute.
When i got Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php i can find this `protected function _getProductCollection()` function. Is this function that is getting the collection from the db?
If yes how to get my custom attribute values in that method?

Or else which is the method that is responsible for getting collection from db and how to get the attribute value in that method?

EDIT:
The purpose is to add some more skus to that collection based on the custom attribute value

Comment: Are you talking about a CATEGORY attribute or a PRODUCT attribute?

Comment: if its product attribute and you need to display it in listing page, please confirm you have set that attribute "available in product listing" to yes

Comment: @Dexter:its a category attribute. And how to get the current category id from that block method?

Answer (score 3):

## Product Attribute

Just add it to this xpath:

```
/config/frontend/product/collection/attributes
```

You can find an example here:

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/config.xml:718
```

## Category Attribute

Just add it to this xpath:

```
/config/frontend/category/collection/attributes
```

You can find an example here:

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/config.xml:742
```

Comment: I am not able to get the current category id itself, I tried with 'echo $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($this->getCategoryId());' but it is not echoing any value to the browser

Comment: And one more thing is i have overridden the function <code>_getProductCollection</code> in my custom module

Comment: again, are we talking about category or product attributes? And yes, sure you can't echo a Mage_Catalog_Model_Categry object. IT IS AN OBJECT! :-) You can try to `echo $this->getCategoryId()` And there is no need to rewrite the `_getProductCollection` method.

Comment: here i am talking about category attribute. With out re writing _getProductCollection how will i modify my collection? echo $this->getCategoryId(); is not outputting the category id from core method also.

Comment: getProductCollection gives you products. This has nothing to do with the category.

Comment: i want to add 4- 10 more products with that collection. I have that sku values in the custom attribute of the current category.But i am not able get the current category id and its custom attribute value. That is where i am stuck

Answer (score 1):

You can make an event observer for `catalog_block_product_list_collection_prepare`.

In config.xml:

```
<global>
    <events>
        <catalog_block_product_list_collection_prepare>
            <observers>
                <add_custom_products>
                    <type>model</type>
                    <class>my_module/observer</class>
                    <method>productListCollectionAddCustomProducts</method>
                </add_custom_products>
            </observers>
        </catalog_block_product_list_collection_prepare>
    </events>
</global>
```

In MyModule/Model/Observer.php:

```
public function productListCollectionAddCustomProducts(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    /* @var $collection Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection */
    $collection = $observer->getCollection();
    $filters = $collection->getLimitationFilters();
    if (!isset($filters['category_id']) || empty($filters['category_id']) || !is_string($filters['category_id'])) {
        return;
    }

    $categoryId = $filters['category_id'];
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
    $myCustomParam = $category->getMyCustomParam();

    if ($myCustomParam == "something") {
        // ...
        // $collection->addItem($product);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple way, without using object manager

```
<?php 
    $catalogHelperData = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data');
    $categoryObject = $catalogHelperData->getCategory();
    $categoryId = $categoryObject->getId();
    $categoryName = $categoryObject->getName();
?>
```